# Probability of winning the world series (Giants vs Yankees)

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

> What is the probability that the Giants will win the World Series against the Yankees if the probability that they win a given game is 0.6?  Winning 4 games means you win the series (7 total games).

I'm thinking binomial probability given they have to win "at least 4 games":

$P(x) = {7\choose4}(0.6)^4(0.4)^3 + {7\choose5}(0.6)^5(0.4)^2 + {7\choose6}(0.6)^6(0.4)^1 + {7\choose7}(0.6)^7(0.4)^0$

Am I on the right track?

Comment: You are correct. Another way of thinking this is if Giant wins in first 4 games, it's $(0.6)^4$. If wins in first $5$ games, it's ${4\choose 1}(0.6)^4(0.4)^1$. If wins in first $6$ games, it's ${5\choose 2}(0.6)^4(0.4)^2$. If wins in first $7$ games, it's ${6\choose 3}(0.6)^4(0.4)^3$. This sum matches the result of your answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, and the method you used is the simplest for such problems.

The logic is that once the Giants win $4$ games at any stage, they win, whatever happens later.